# Nested KMM Package Not referenced correctly

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kmm

I am trying to used 2 KMM packages inside of my iOS app however its not being referenced correctly.

Here is my dependency structure:

```
iOSApp
 + KmmPackageOne
 + KmmPackageTwo

KmmPackageOne
 + KmmPackageTwo
```

Here are the example files im trying to use in the iOSApp

```
// In KmmPackageOne, class Foo.kt
class Foo {
  fun bar() { ... }
}

// In KmmPackageTwo, class Buzz.kt
class Buzz(
  private val foo: Foo
) {
  ...
}
```

When adding them to the iOS app, it doesn't understand that parameter foo is from KmmPackageOne

```
// in swift class
...
val buzz = Buzz(foo: Foo())
```

the following error is thrown

```
Argument type `Foo` does not conform to expected type `KPTFoo`
```

I've assumed KPT means KmmPackageTwo. So it seems XCode has added a layer of abstraction to the KmmPackageTwo in KmmPackageOne.

build.gradle of KmmPackageOne

```
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            kotlin.srcDir('src/commonMain/kotlin')
            dependencies {
                implementation("locationOf:KmmPackageTwo:+")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to import 2 Xcode Frameworks that were built with Kotlin separately, you can't do that. I just answered a similar question today.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67403855/227313

You need to build 1 Xcode Framework that has all of your Kotlin modules.